# Is a complex symmetric square matrix with zero diagonal diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, symmetric-matrices

Let $A$ be a complex symmetric square matrix, and set the diagonal to 0. Thus $a_{ii} = 0$ for all $1\leq i \leq n$. I am wondering if $A$ is always diagonalizable. I read that almost all complex symmetric square matrices are diagonalizable, and thought that perhaps the zero diagonal would simplify things sufficiently to allow a proof for arbitrary $A$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & i \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ i & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}.$$Its characteristic polynomial is $-x^3$ and therefore, if it was diagonalizable, it would be the null matrix. But it isn't. Therefore, $A$ is a complex symmetric matrix with only $0$'s in the main diagonal which is not diagonalizable.

Answer (score 1):

page 209 in Horn and Johnson, Matrix Analysis, say (well, it is part of something else)
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
0 & 1 & -i & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & i \\
-i & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & i & 1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
is not similar to a diagonal matrix. Worth checking by hand. The characteristic polynomial is $x^4,$ the minimal polynomial is $x^2.$ So Jose's argument applies.

Let me add that a symmetric complex matrix $M$ is **congruent** to a diagonal matrix: there is a matrix $P$ with $\det P \neq 0$ so that $P^T MP = D$ is diagonal.